# How can I calculate exact median with Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

This [page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/api/core/spark/api/java/JavaDoubleRDD.html) contains some statistics functions (mean, stdev, variance, etc.) but it does not contain the median. How can I calculate exact median?

Comment: the percentile_approx does not work for groups with even number of  entries. To make it work there, a probable workaround is to take the average of 50th percentile and the next value. In pyspark something below works..

`((F.percentile_approx('val', 0.5)+ F.percentile_approx('val', 0.500000000001))*.5).alias('med_val2')
  )`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to sort RDD and take element in the middle or average of two elements. Here is example with RDD[Int]:

```
  import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

  val rdd: RDD[Int] = ???

  val sorted = rdd.sortBy(identity).zipWithIndex().map {
    case (v, idx) => (idx, v)
  }

  val count = sorted.count()

  val median: Double = if (count % 2 == 0) {
    val l = count / 2 - 1
    val r = l + 1
    (sorted.lookup(l).head + sorted.lookup(r).head).toDouble / 2
  } else sorted.lookup(count / 2).head.toDouble
```

Comment: what is this "lookup" method ? AFAIK it does not exist in RDD.

Comment: @javadba yeah, you need to import SparkContext._ to bring  PairRDD implicits in scope

Comment: p.s. I think that there are faster algorithms for finding median that don't require full sorting (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm)

Comment: unfortunately they are not applicable to distributed RDD

Comment: Can DataFrame API be used instead of RDD API?

Comment: Yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432843/how-to-find-median-using-spark

Comment: @EugeneZhulenev It would be better to persist the sorted RDD so it that it won't recompute the DAG while doing lookups

Answer (score 7):

Using **Spark 2.0+** and the DataFrame API you can use the [`approxQuantile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions) method：

```
def approxQuantile(col: String, probabilities: Array[Double], relativeError: Double)
```

It will also work on multiple columns at the same time since Spark version 2.2. By setting  `probabilites` to `Array(0.5)` and `relativeError` to 0, it will compute the exact median. From the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions):

> The relative target precision to achieve (greater than or equal to 0). If set to zero, the exact quantiles are computed, which could be very expensive.

Despite this, there seems to be some issues with the precision when setting `relativeError` to 0, see the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669324/approxquantile-give-incorrect-median-in-spark-scala). A low error close to 0 will in some instances work better (will depend on Spark version).

---

A small working example which calculates the median of the numbers from 1 to 99 (both inclusive) and uses a low `relativeError`:

```
val df = (1 to 99).toDF("num")
val median = df.stat.approxQuantile("num", Array(0.5), 0.001)(0)
println(median)
```

The median returned is 50.0.

Comment: Monica, do you know why when I run your code, I get NameError: name 'Array' is not defined? this does not seem like it's a package i need to import

Comment: @mathlover: Are you using Scala? Maybe you overwrite the name somewhere with a variable?

Comment: I am using PySpark

Comment: @mathlover: Then it's not surprising you can't use a Scala version straight off. You need to adapt it a bit.