# How to find median and quantiles using Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, median, rdd, pyspark

How can I find median of an `RDD` of integers using a distributed method, IPython, and Spark? The `RDD` is approximately 700,000 elements and therefore too large to collect and find the median.

This question is similar to this question: [How can I calculate exact median with Apache Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158729/how-can-i-calculate-exact-median-with-apache-spark). However, the answer to the question is in Scala, which I do not know.

Using the thinking for the Scala answer, I am trying to write a similar solution in Python.

I know I first want to sort the `RDD`. I do not know how. I see the `sortBy` (Sorts this RDD by the given `keyfunc`) and `sortByKey` (Sorts this `RDD`, which is assumed to consist of (key, value) pairs.) methods. I think both use key value and my `RDD` only has integer elements.

1. First, I was thinking of doing `myrdd.sortBy(lambda x: x)`?
2. Next I will find the length of the rdd (`rdd.count()`).
3. Finally, I want to find the element or 2 elements at the center of the RDD. I need help with this method too.

EDIT:

I had an idea. Maybe I can index my `RDD` and then key = index and value = element. And then I can try to sort by value? I don't know if this is possible because there is only a `sortByKey` method.

Comment: Well, with 7e5 integers, assuming 64 bits each, you need around 5MB to store all the data and it takes a fraction of second to compute median locally using `np.median` :) Sure, you can sort and index as you described but my guess it will be around and order of magnitude slower.

Comment: zero323: Perhaps it's a Spark cluster running on a cluster of Commodore 64s.

Comment: @DanielDarabos That's a wicked idea :) And tape decks as the HDFS replacement...

Comment: Here is how to do it with Pyspark Dataframe AP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743476/how-to-find-the-median-in-apache-spark-with-python-dataframe-api/38743477#38743477

Answer (score 147, accepted):

#### Ongoing work

[SPARK-30569](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-30569) - *Add DSL functions invoking percentile_approx*

#### Spark 2.0+:

You can use `approxQuantile` method which implements [Greenwald-Khanna algorithm](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~datar/courses/cs361a/papers/quantiles.pdf):

**Python**:

```
df.approxQuantile("x", [0.5], 0.25)
```

**Scala**:

```
df.stat.approxQuantile("x", Array(0.5), 0.25)
```

where the last parameter is a relative error. The lower the number the more accurate results and more expensive computation.

Since Spark 2.2 ([SPARK-14352](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14352)) it supports estimation on multiple columns:

```
df.approxQuantile(["x", "y", "z"], [0.5], 0.25)
```

and

```
df.approxQuantile(Array("x", "y", "z"), Array(0.5), 0.25)
```

Underlying methods can be also used in SQL aggregation (both global and groped) using [`approx_percentile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#approx_percentile) function:

```sql
> SELECT approx_percentile(10.0, array(0.5, 0.4, 0.1), 100);
 [10.0,10.0,10.0]
> SELECT approx_percentile(10.0, 0.5, 100);
 10.0
```

#### Spark < 2.0

**Python**

As I've mentioned in the comments it is most likely not worth all the fuss. If data is relatively small like in your case then simply collect and compute median locally:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(323)
rdd = sc.parallelize(np.random.randint(1000000, size=700000))

%time np.median(rdd.collect())
np.array(rdd.collect()).nbytes
```

It takes around 0.01 second on my few years old computer and around 5.5MB of memory.

If data is much larger sorting will be a limiting factor so instead of getting an exact value it is probably better to sample, collect, and compute locally. But if you really want a to use Spark something like this should do the trick (if I didn't mess up anything):

```
from numpy import floor
import time

def quantile(rdd, p, sample=None, seed=None):
    """Compute a quantile of order p ∈ [0, 1]
    :rdd a numeric rdd
    :p quantile(between 0 and 1)
    :sample fraction of and rdd to use. If not provided we use a whole dataset
    :seed random number generator seed to be used with sample
    """
    assert 0 <= p <= 1
    assert sample is None or 0 < sample <= 1

    seed = seed if seed is not None else time.time()
    rdd = rdd if sample is None else rdd.sample(False, sample, seed)

    rddSortedWithIndex = (rdd.
        sortBy(lambda x: x).
        zipWithIndex().
        map(lambda (x, i): (i, x)).
        cache())

    n = rddSortedWithIndex.count()
    h = (n - 1) * p

    rddX, rddXPlusOne = (
        rddSortedWithIndex.lookup(x)[0]
        for x in int(floor(h)) + np.array([0L, 1L]))

    return rddX + (h - floor(h)) * (rddXPlusOne - rddX)
```

And some tests:

```
np.median(rdd.collect()), quantile(rdd, 0.5)
## (500184.5, 500184.5)
np.percentile(rdd.collect(), 25), quantile(rdd, 0.25)
## (250506.75, 250506.75)
np.percentile(rdd.collect(), 75), quantile(rdd, 0.75)
(750069.25, 750069.25)
```

Finally lets define median:

```
from functools import partial
median = partial(quantile, p=0.5)
```

So far so good but it takes 4.66 s in a local mode without any network communication. There is probably way to improve this, but why even bother?

**Language independent** (*Hive UDAF*):

If you use `HiveContext` you can also use Hive UDAFs. With integral values:

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (float(x), )).toDF(["x"]).registerTempTable("df")

sqlContext.sql("SELECT percentile_approx(x, 0.5) FROM df")
```

With continuous values:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT percentile(x, 0.5) FROM df")
```

In `percentile_approx` you can pass an additional argument which determines a number of records to use.

Comment: Will it be possible in Spark 2.0 to use approxQuantile() with window functions? For example, if it is necessary to calculate a moving median on a DataFrame.

Comment: @user3791111 Unlikely and there would be no value in that. When you use window functions you can get exact value in window with no additional cost.

Comment: OK, exact or approximate - whatever, will there be any way to calculate "moving median" (NOT "moving average") in Spark 2.0?

Answer (score 12):

Here is the method I used using window functions (with pyspark 2.2.0).

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

class median():
    """ Create median class with over method to pass partition """
    def __init__(self, df, col, name):
        assert col
        self.column=col
        self.df = df
        self.name = name

    def over(self, window):
        from pyspark.sql.functions import percent_rank, pow, first

        first_window = window.orderBy(self.column)                                  # first, order by column we want to compute the median for
        df = self.df.withColumn("percent_rank", percent_rank().over(first_window))  # add percent_rank column, percent_rank = 0.5 corresponds to median
        second_window = window.orderBy(pow(df.percent_rank-0.5, 2))                 # order by (percent_rank - 0.5)^2 ascending
        return df.withColumn(self.name, first(self.column).over(second_window))     # the first row of the window corresponds to median

def addMedian(self, col, median_name):
    """ Method to be added to spark native DataFrame class """
    return median(self, col, median_name)

# Add method to DataFrame class
DataFrame.addMedian = addMedian
```

Then call the addMedian method to calculate the median of col2:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window

median_window = Window.partitionBy("col1")
df = df.addMedian("col2", "median").over(median_window)
```

Finally you can group by if needed.

```
df.groupby("col1", "median")
```

Note: as stated by @Ihor in the comments, in case of an even number of elements, it will only return an approximation of the median and not the exact value as expected by the mathematical definition.

Comment: should i be adding something else since I tried it and NameError: name 'DataFrame' is not defined ..

Comment: You are right, the imports were missing. I updated the answer accordingly. Thanks

Comment: That won't work for even numbers in a group: the median will be bad.  It must be the average between two middle elements.

Comment: @BenoîtCarne how is this `DataFrame.addMedian = addMedian` line working? what is it called in Python?

Comment: @Shankar Not sure it has an official Python name! I would call it "adding a function to a class after it has been defined". More info about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455111/define-a-method-outside-of-class-definition
I did it just to be able to call the addMedian function as if it had been implemented natively in Spark. It is not mandatory.

Comment: I like how you added the method to DataFrame. However, Ihor's comment is still valid - the median is an approximation rather than the correct value.

Comment: @ZygD Yes you are right. I don't have a fix for that at the moment. However for my use case the approximation was enough.

Comment: @Shankar in general it's called [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch): "In Ruby, Python, and many other dynamic programming languages, the term monkey patch only refers to dynamic modifications of a class or module at runtime, motivated by the intent to patch existing third-party code as a workaround to a bug or feature which does not act as desired."

Answer (score 8):

Adding a solution if you want an RDD method only and dont want to move to DF.
This snippet can get you a percentile for an RDD of double.

If you input percentile as 50, you should obtain your required median.
Let me know if there are any corner cases not accounted for.

```
/**
  * Gets the nth percentile entry for an RDD of doubles
  *
  * @param inputScore : Input scores consisting of a RDD of doubles
  * @param percentile : The percentile cutoff required (between 0 to 100), e.g 90%ile of [1,4,5,9,19,23,44] = ~23.
  *                     It prefers the higher value when the desired quantile lies between two data points
  * @return : The number best representing the percentile in the Rdd of double
  */    
  def getRddPercentile(inputScore: RDD[Double], percentile: Double): Double = {
    val numEntries = inputScore.count().toDouble
    val retrievedEntry = (percentile * numEntries / 100.0 ).min(numEntries).max(0).toInt


    inputScore
      .sortBy { case (score) => score }
      .zipWithIndex()
      .filter { case (score, index) => index == retrievedEntry }
      .map { case (score, index) => score }
      .collect()(0)
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways that can be used. One is using [approxQuantile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.approxQuantile.html) method and the other [percentile_approx](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx.html) method. However, both the methods might not give accurate results when there are even number of records. The workaround is to take average as shown below.

```
importpyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx as F
# df.select(F.percentile_approx("COLUMN_NAME_FOR_WHICH_MEDIAN_TO_BE_COMPUTED", 0.5).alias("MEDIAN)) # might not give proper results when there are even number of records

((
df.select(F.percentile_approx("COLUMN_NAME_FOR_WHICH_MEDIAN_TO_BE_COMPUTED", 0.5) + df.select(F.percentile_approx("COLUMN_NAME_FOR_WHICH_MEDIAN_TO_BE_COMPUTED", 0.500001)
)*.5).alias("MEDIAN))
```

Answer (score 2):

I have written the function which takes data frame as an input and returns a dataframe which has median as an output over a partition and order_col is the column for which we want to calculate median for part_col is the level at which we want to calculate median for :

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def calculate_median(dataframe, part_col, order_col):
    win = Window.partitionBy(*part_col).orderBy(order_col)
#     count_row = dataframe.groupby(*part_col).distinct().count()
    dataframe.persist()
    dataframe.count()
    temp = dataframe.withColumn("rank", F.row_number().over(win))
    temp = temp.withColumn(
        "count_row_part",
        F.count(order_col).over(Window.partitionBy(part_col))
    )
    temp = temp.withColumn(
        "even_flag",
        F.when(
            F.col("count_row_part") %2 == 0,
            F.lit(1)
        ).otherwise(
            F.lit(0)
        )
    ).withColumn(
        "mid_value",
        F.floor(F.col("count_row_part")/2)
    )

    temp = temp.withColumn(
        "avg_flag",
        F.when(
            (F.col("even_flag")==1) &
            (F.col("rank") == F.col("mid_value"))|
            ((F.col("rank")-1) == F.col("mid_value")),
            F.lit(1)
        ).otherwise(
        F.when(
            F.col("rank") == F.col("mid_value")+1,
            F.lit(1)
            )
        )
    )
    temp.show(10)
    return temp.filter(
        F.col("avg_flag") == 1
    ).groupby(
        part_col + ["avg_flag"]
    ).agg(
        F.avg(F.col(order_col)).alias("median")
    ).drop("avg_flag")
```

Answer (score 2):

**From version 3.4+** the [`median`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.median.html#pyspark.sql.functions.median) function is available directly.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.groupBy("grp").agg(f.median("val"))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Spark, calculating quantiles (**median, quartiles, percentiles**, etc.) in a dataframe can be done either accurately or approximately.

**Sample dataframe:**

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.range(1, 6)
df.show()
# +---+
# | id|
# +---+
# |  1|
# |  2|
# |  3|
# |  4|
# |  5|
# +---+
```

**Median:**

- accurate, but resource-intensive for big data

  - `F.median('id')` - from Spark 3.4+

    ```py
    df.agg(F.median('id')).head()[0]
    # 3.0
    ```
  - `F.expr('percentile(id, .5)')`

    ```py
    df.agg(F.expr('percentile(id, .5)')).head()[0]
    # 3.0
    ```
- approximate, but efficient for big data
  `F.percentile_approx('id', .5)`

  ```py
  df.agg(F.percentile_approx('id', .5)).head()[0]
  # 3
  ```

**Lower quartile:**

- accurate, but resource-intensive for big data
  `F.expr('percentile(id, .25)')`

  ```py
  df.agg(F.expr('percentile(id, .25)')).head()[0]
  # 2.0
  ```
- approximate, but efficient for big data
  `F.percentile_approx('id', .25)`

  ```py
  df.agg(F.percentile_approx('id', .25)).head()[0]
  # 2
  ```

**Upper quartile:**

- accurate, but resource-intensive for big data
  `F.expr('percentile(id, .75)')`

  ```py
  df.agg(F.expr('percentile(id, .75)')).head()[0]
  # 4.0
  ```
- approximate, but efficient for big data
  `F.percentile_approx('id', .75)`

  ```py
  df.agg(F.percentile_approx('id', .75)).head()[0]
  # 4
  ```

**All quartiles:**

- accurate, but resource-intensive for big data
  `F.expr('percentile(id, array(.25, .5, .75))')`

  ```py
  df.agg(F.expr('percentile(id, array(.25, .5, .75))')).head()[0]
  # [2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
  ```
- approximate, but efficient for big data
  `F.percentile_approx('id', [.25, .5, .75])`

  ```py
  df.agg(F.percentile_approx('id', [.25, .5, .75])).head()[0]
  # [2, 3, 4]
  ```

**Other quantiles** (e.g. percentiles) can be calculated using the same approach (functions [`percentile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#percentile) or [`percentile_approx`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx.html#pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx)).

Answer (score 0):

For exact median computation you can use the following function and use it with PySpark DataFrame API:

```
def median_exact(col: Union[Column, str]) -> Column:
    """
    For grouped aggregations, Spark provides a way via pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx("col", .5) function,
    since for large datasets, computing the median is computationally expensive.
    This function manually computes the median and should only be used for small to mid sized datasets / groupings.
    :param col: Column to compute the median for.
    :return: A pyspark `Column` containing the median calculation expression
    """
    list_expr = F.filter(F.collect_list(col), lambda x: x.isNotNull())
    sorted_list_expr = F.sort_array(list_expr)
    size_expr = F.size(sorted_list_expr)

    even_num_elements = (size_expr % 2) == 0
    odd_num_elements = ~even_num_elements

    return F.when(size_expr == 0, None).otherwise(
        F.when(odd_num_elements, sorted_list_expr[F.floor(size_expr / 2)]).otherwise(
            (
                sorted_list_expr[(size_expr / 2 - 1).cast("long")]
                + sorted_list_expr[(size_expr / 2).cast("long")]
            )
            / 2
        )
    )
```

Apply it like this:

```
output_df = input_spark_df.groupby("group").agg(
    median_exact("elems").alias("elems_median")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can calculate the median and quantiles in spark using the following code:

```
df.stat.approxQuantile(col,[quantiles],error)
```

For example, finding the median in the following dataframe `[1,2,3,4,5]`:

```
df.stat.approxQuantile(col,[0.5],0)
```

The lesser the error, the more accurate the results.