# PySpark 1.5 Groupby Sum for new column in Dataframe

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a new column ("newaggCol") in a Spark Dataframe using groupBy and sum (with PySpark 1.5).  My numeric columns have been cast to either Long or Double. The columns used to form the groupBy are String and Timestamp. My code is as follows

```
df= df.withColumn("newaggCol",(df.groupBy([df.strCol,df.tsCol]).sum(df.longCol)))
```

My traceback for the error is coming to that line. And stating:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and',     '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

I feel that I must be calling the functions incorrectly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible using SQL aggregations but you can easily get the desired result using window functions

```
import sys
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum as sum_

w = (Window()
    .partitionBy(df.strCol, df.tsCol)
    .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing))

df.withColumn("newaggCol", sum_(df.longCol).over(w))
```

Comment: say I want to get quantiles or percentiles on that 'newaggCol', by a new grouping. So I create "new_window=(Window().partitionBy(strcol1,strcol2).orderBy(newaggCol)" THEN, "df.withColumn("pctl",percentRank().over(new_window))"      ??

Comment: If you want the same type of results then window should stay how it is. Although keep in mind these are expensive calls.

Comment: What if I want to calculate the discrete Percentile or Quantile (ie, .5, .95) for the numeric col, 'newaggCol'. I know there is a 'percentRank', but that doesn't give dense or or consecutive quantiles obviously. Is there a way to use a UDF? I'm not sure how to use those?

Comment: There is a quantile discretizer but it doesn't work by group.You may find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/q/32827643/1560062