# SPARK calculate median and IQR on spark dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe of 5 columns and I want to calculate median and Inter quartile range on all.

How do I write `udf` and call them on columns.

Comment: I think you have to sort every column and take the middle value in case of odd, and the average between both middle values if even. i don't know any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm wrong due I'm not an expert, but I think that `UDFs` are more suited to record transformations or operations, than for this.

Comment: Maybe this would help [How to calculate median in Spark SQLContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519549/how-to-claculate-median-in-spark-sqlcontext-for-column-of-data-type-double)

Comment: This question has an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432843/how-to-find-median-and-quantiles-using-spark.