# apache-spark-sql - implement percentile functions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with cassandra + spark + spark-sql. I'n not using Hive.
I'd like to create my custom aggregation function, like:

```
select percentile(column, 0.95) from cassandra_table
```

spark-sql support avg(), min(), etc.: I want to implement others like percentile, but I cannot find documentation on this.

Can someone point me to to any doc or class to start with?

Thanks!

Comment: This could probably help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32101530/935083

Comment: @rchukh Not so much. It is not possible to efficiently implement percentile function with Spark UDAF. I would simply use Hive UDF: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34521857/1560062 (and just to clarify Hive UDFs are not Hive specific).