# Finding Median on Column in Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, median

I have a dataframe with column `Salary`. I have to find out the median on this column using Spark SQL and SCALA.
Spark version 1.6.0 and Scala version is 2.10.5.

I have registered Dataframe as table and fired below query.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.random.RandomRDDs

sqlContext.sql("SELECT percentile_approx(salary, 0.5) FROM employee").show()
```

The Data frame is created from CSV and has rows(Header + data rows). Data rows are odd in number. While firing above query it is giving me result in decimal values.

Data looks like this(from CSV):

```
salary; name;    job;    gender

1000;    AA;    private;  M

2000;    BB;    public;   M
```

Please help me to find the correct solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519549/how-to-calculate-median-in-spark-sqlcontext-for-column-of-data-type-double

Comment: what is the count in dataframe if you skip headers?

Comment: please share example data.

Comment: The count is odd after skipping header. Please check the data above.

Comment: The issue is Median is coming out as decimal value even if the count is odd and no columns values are in decimal.