# Grouped percentile using SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I want to calculate grouped percentiles using SparkR. I tried this

```
library(SparkR)
mtcars_spark %>% 
      SparkR::groupBy("cyl") %>%
      SparkR::summarize(p75 = approxQuantile("mpg", 0.75, 0.01),
                        p90 = approxQuantile("mpg", 0.90, 0.01),
                        p99 = approxQuantile("mpg", 0.99, 0.01))
```

...but, got this error:

```
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘approxQuantile’ for signature ‘"GroupedData", "character", "numeric", "numeric"’
```

How can I get the grouped percentiles using SparkR so that the desired output is the same as from the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(p75 = quantile(mpg, 0.75),
            p90 = quantile(mpg, 0.90),
            p99 = quantile(mpg, 0.99))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`approxQuantile` is a method which operates on `Datasets` - it has no variant that work on `*GroupedDataset`. If you've enabled Hive support, you use Hive's `percentile` UDF:

```
mtcars_spark %>% 
    SparkR::groupBy("cyl") %>%
    SparkR::summarize(p75 = expr("percentile(mpg, 0.75)"),
                      p90 = expr("percentile(mpg, 0.90)"),
                      p99 = expr("percentile(mpg, 0.99)"))
```

If not you could try `gapply` function, but it is likely to be much less efficient.

Comment: Do I need to load any library to use Hive's percentile function?

Comment: wow...That worked! Thanks!! Where can I read more about this?

Comment: [Hive Language Manual - UDF section](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF). You can also check https://stackoverflow.com/q/52049152/6910411 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/34519549/6910411