# How to find the median in Apache Spark with Python Dataframe API?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, median

PySpark API provides many aggregate functions except the median. Spark 2 comes with `approxQuantile` which gives approximate quantiles but exact median is very expensive to calculate. Is there a more PySpark way of calculating median for a column of values in a Spark Dataframe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example implementation with Dataframe API in Python (Spark 1.6 +).

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
```

Let's assume we have monthly salaries for customers in "salaries" spark dataframe such as:

**month | customer_id | salary**

and we would like to find the median salary per customer throughout all the months

Step1: Write a user defined function to calculate the median

```
def find_median(values_list):
    try:
        median = np.median(values_list) #get the median of values in a list in each row
        return round(float(median),2)
    except Exception:
        return None #if there is anything wrong with the given values

median_finder = F.udf(find_median,FloatType())
```

Step 2: Aggregate on the salary column by collecting them into a list of salaries in each row:

```
salaries_list = salaries.groupBy("customer_id").agg(F.collect_list("salary").alias("salaries"))
```

Step 3: Call the median_finder udf on the salaries column and add the median values as a new column

```
salaries_list = salaries_list.withColumn("median",median_finder("salaries"))
```

Comment: using np.nanmedian(values_list) ignores NaNs and is sometimes a better choice

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What's the performance of this `np.median(values_list)` compared to the `approxQuantile` method provided by Spark?

Answer (score 1):

For **exact median** (for small-mid sized dataframes), since **Spark 2.1** one can use [`percentile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#percentile) function wrapped in `expr`:

```
F.expr('percentile(c2, 0.5)')
```

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 10),
     (1, 20),
     (2, 50)],
    ['c1', 'c2'])
df.groupby('c1').agg(F.expr('percentile(c2, 0.5)').alias('median')).show()
#  +---+------+
#  | c1|median|
#  +---+------+
#  |  1|  15.0|
#  |  2|  50.0|
#  +---+------+
df.withColumn('median', F.expr('percentile(c2, 0.5)').over(W.partitionBy('c1'))).show()
#  +---+---+------+
#  | c1| c2|median|
#  +---+---+------+
#  |  1| 10|  15.0|
#  |  1| 20|  15.0|
#  |  2| 50|  50.0|
#  +---+---+------+
```

**Approximate median** can often be a better choice for mid-large sized dataframes.

**Spark 2.1** implements [`approx_percentile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#approx_percentile) and [`percentile_approx`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#percentile_approx):

```
F.expr('percentile_approx(c2, 0.5)')
```

Since **Spark 3.1** one can use it in [PySpark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx.html#pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx) API directly:

```
F.percentile_approx('c2', 0.5)
```