# How to find exact median for grouped data in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to calculate exact median on grouped data set of Double datatype in Spark using Scala.

It is different from the similar query: [Find median in spark SQL for multiple double datatype columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404041). This question is about the finding data for grouped data, whereas the other one is about finding median on a RDD level.

Here is my sample data

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("select * from test").show()

+---+---+
| id|num|
+---+---+
|  A|0.0|
|  A|1.0|
|  A|1.0|
|  A|1.0|
|  A|0.0|
|  A|1.0|
|  B|0.0|
|  B|1.0|
|  B|1.0|
+---+---+
```

Expected Answer:

```
+--------+
| Median |
+--------+
|   1    |
|   1    |
+--------+
```

I tried the following option, but no luck:

1) Hive function percentile, it worked only for BigInt.

2) Hive function `percentile_approx`, but it does not work as expected (returns 0.25 vs 1).

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("select percentile_approx(num, 0.5) from test group by id").show()

+----+
| _c0|
+----+
|0.25|
|0.25|
+----+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Simplest Approach (requires Spark 2.0.1+ and not exact median)

As noted in the comments in reference to the first question [Find median in Spark SQL for double datatype columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404041/find-median-in-spark-sql-for-multiple-double-datatype-columns), we can use `percentile_approx` to calculate median for Spark 2.0.1+.  To apply this for grouped data in Apache Spark, the query would look like:

```
val df = Seq(("A", 0.0), ("A", 0.0), ("A", 1.0), ("A", 1.0), ("A", 1.0), ("A", 1.0), ("B", 0.0), ("B", 1.0), ("B", 1.0)).toDF("id", "num")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
spark.sql("select id, percentile_approx(num, 0.5) as median from df group by id order by id").show()
```

with the output being:

```
+---+------+
| id|median|
+---+------+
|  A|   1.0|
|  B|   1.0|
+---+------+
```

Saying this, this is an *approximate value* (as opposed to an exact median per the question).

#### Calculate exact median for grouped data

There are multiple approaches so I'm sure others in SO can provide better or more efficient examples.  But here's a code snippet calculate the median for grouped data in Spark (verified in Spark 1.6 and Spark 2.1):

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

val rdd: RDD[(String, Double)] = sc.parallelize(Seq(("A", 1.0), ("A", 0.0), ("A", 1.0), ("A", 1.0), ("A", 0.0), ("A", 1.0), ("B", 0.0), ("B", 1.0), ("B", 1.0)))

// Scala median function
def median(inputList: List[Double]): Double = {
  val count = inputList.size
  if (count % 2 == 0) {
    val l = count / 2 - 1
    val r = l + 1
    (inputList(l) + inputList(r)).toDouble / 2
  } else
    inputList(count / 2).toDouble
}

// Sort the values
val setRDD = rdd.groupByKey()
val sortedListRDD = setRDD.mapValues(_.toList.sorted)

// Output DataFrame of id and median
sortedListRDD.map(m => {
  (m._1, median(m._2))
}).toDF("id", "median_of_num").show()
```

with the output being:

```
+---+-------------+
| id|median_of_num|
+---+-------------+
|  A|          1.0|
|  B|          1.0|
+---+-------------+
```

There are some caveats that I should call out as this likely isn't the most efficient implementation:

- It's currently using a `groupByKey` which is not very performant.  You may want to change this into a `reduceByKey` instead (more information at [Avoid GroupByKey](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html))
- Using a Scala function to calculate the `median`.

This approach should work okay for smaller amounts of data but if you have millions of rows for each key, would advise utilizing Spark 2.0.1+ and using the `percentile_approx` approach.

Comment: Not that I can think of as median is a lot trickier to do in a distributed environment. Hence the reason for percentile_approx in Spark 2.0.

Comment: Can we avoid creation of temp view?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of PERCENTILE_COUNT function in SPARK. This can be used to find the value of median for a grouped data in Dataframe. Hope it may help someone. Feel free to provide your suggestions to improve the solution.

```
val PERCENTILEFLOOR = udf((maxrank: Integer, percentile: Double) => scala.math.floor(1 + (percentile * (maxrank - 1))))

  val PERCENTILECEIL = udf((maxrank: Integer, percentile: Double) => scala.math.ceil(1 + (percentile * (maxrank - 1))))

  val PERCENTILECALC = udf((maxrank: Integer, percentile: Double, floorVal: Double, ceilVal: Double, floorNum: Double, ceilNum: Double)
=> {
    if (ceilNum == floorNum) {
      floorVal
    } else {
      val RN = (1 + (percentile * (maxrank - 1)))
      ((ceilNum - RN) * floorVal) + ((RN - floorNum) * ceilVal)
    }   })



/**    * The result of PERCENTILE_CONT is computed by linear interpolation between values after ordering them.    * Using the percentile value (P) and the number of rows (N) in the aggregation group,    * we compute the row number we are interested in after ordering the rows with respect to the sort specification.    * This row number (RN) is computed according to the formula RN = (1+ (P*(N-1)).    * The final result of the aggregate function is computed by linear interpolation between the values from rows at row numbers   
* CRN = CEILING(RN) and FRN = FLOOR(RN).    *    * The final result will be:    *    * If (CRN = FRN = RN) then the result is    * (value of expression from row at RN)    * Otherwise the result is    * (CRN - RN) * (value of expression for row at FRN) +    * (RN - FRN) * (value of expression for row at CRN)    *    * Parameter details    *    * @inputDF - Dataframe for computation    * @medianCol - Column for which percentile to be calculated    * @grouplist - Group list for dataframe before sorting    * @percentile - numeric value between 0 and 1 to express the percentile to be calculated    *    */

  def percentile_count(inputDF: DataFrame, medianCol: String, groupList: List[String], percentile: Double): DataFrame = {
    val orderList = List(medianCol)

    val wSpec3 = Window.partitionBy(groupList.head, groupList.tail: _*).orderBy(orderList.head, orderList.tail: _*)
    //   Group, sort and rank the DF
    val rankedDF = inputDF.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(wSpec3))

    // Find the maximum for each group 
    val groupedMaxDF = rankedDF.groupBy(groupList.head, groupList.tail: _*).agg(max("rank").as("maxval"))

    // CRN calculation
    val ceilNumDF = groupedMaxDF.withColumn("rank", PERCENTILECEIL(groupedMaxDF("maxval"), lit(percentile))).drop("maxval")

    // FRN calculation
    val floorNumDF = groupedMaxDF.withColumn("rank", PERCENTILEFLOOR(groupedMaxDF("maxval"), lit(percentile)))

    val ntileGroup = "rank" :: groupList

    //Get the values for the CRN and FRN 
    val floorDF = floorNumDF.join(rankedDF, ntileGroup).withColumnRenamed("rank", "floorNum").withColumnRenamed(medianCol, "floorVal")
    val ceilDF = ceilNumDF.join(rankedDF, ntileGroup).withColumnRenamed("rank", "ceilNum").withColumnRenamed(medianCol, "ceilVal")

    //Get both the values for CRN and FRN in same row
    val resultDF = floorDF.join(ceilDF, groupList)

    val finalList = "median_" + medianCol :: groupList

    // Calculate the median using the UDF PERCENTILECALC and returns the DF
    resultDF.withColumn("median_" + medianCol, PERCENTILECALC(resultDF("maxval"), lit(percentile), resultDF("floorVal"), resultDF("ceilVal"), resultDF("floorNum"), resultDF("ceilNum"))).select(finalList.head, finalList.tail: _*)

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for exact median. I described spark sql solution here [gist.github](https://gist.github.com/daniarleagk/6df2f695f2397fa38a9cf70f9c829d0e). 
 To compute exact median I use row_number() and count() functions in conjuction with a window function.

```
val data1 = Array( ("a", 0), ("a", 1), ("a", 1), ("a", 1), ("a", 0), ("a", 1))
val data2 = Array( ("b", 0), ("b", 1), ("b", 1))
val union = data1.union(data2)
val df = sc.parallelize(union).toDF("key", "val")
df.cache.createOrReplaceTempView("kvTable")
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=2")


var ds = spark.sql("""
   SELECT key, avg(val) as median
FROM ( SELECT key, val, rN, (CASE WHEN cN % 2 = 0 then (cN DIV 2) ELSE (cN DIV 2) + 1 end) as m1, (cN DIV 2) + 1 as m2 
        FROM ( 
            SELECT key, val, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY key ORDER BY val ) as rN, count(val) OVER (PARTITION BY key ) as cN
            FROM kvTable
         ) s
    ) r
WHERE rN BETWEEN m1 and m2
GROUP BY key 
""")
```

Spark executes and optimizes this query efficiently, since it reuses data partitioning.

```
scala> ds.show
+---+------+
|key|median|
+---+------+
|  a|   1.0|
|  b|   1.0|
+---+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

with high order function `element_at` added in Spark 2.4. We could use with Window function, or groupBy then join back.

**Sample Data**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class Salary(depName: String, empNo: Long, salary: Long)
val empsalary = Seq(
  Salary("sales", 1, 5000),
  Salary("personnel", 2, 3900),
  Salary("sales", 3, 4800),
  Salary("sales", 4, 4800),
  Salary("personnel", 5, 3500),
  Salary("develop", 7, 4200),
  Salary("develop", 8, 6000),
  Salary("develop", 9, 4500),
  Salary("develop", 10, 5200),
  Salary("develop", 11, 5200)).toDS
```

**with Window function**

```
val byDepName = Window.partitionBy('depName).orderBy('salary)
val df = empsalary.withColumn(
  "salaries", collect_list('salary) over byDepName).withColumn(
  "median_salary", element_at('salaries, (size('salaries)/2 + 1).cast("int")))

df.show(false)
```

**with groupBy then join back**

```
val dfMedian = empsalary.groupBy("depName").agg(
  sort_array(collect_list('salary)).as("salaries")).select(
  'depName, 
  element_at('salaries, (size('salaries)/2 + 1).cast("int")).as("median_salary"))
empsalary.join(dfMedian, "depName").show(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna use spark-sql (as I do) you can use the `cume_dist` function.

See example below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val df = (1 to 10).toSeq.toDF
val win = Window.
    partitionBy(F.col("value")).
    orderBy(F.col("value")).
    rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
df.withColumn("c", F.cume_dist().over(win)).show
```

Results:

```
+-----+---+
|value|  c|
+-----+---+
|    1|0.1|
|    2|0.2|
|    3|0.3|
|    4|0.4|
|    5|0.5|
|    6|0.6|
|    7|0.7|
|    8|0.8|
|    9|0.9|
|   10|1.0|
+-----+---+
```

The median is the value for which `df("c")` equals 0.5.
I hope it helps, Elior.

Comment: Same codes result in different output with 1.0 all c values.

Comment: Hi @ErkanŞirin, not sure what you mean by that.
The window spec: `rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)`
should take care for the running-sum on column _c_

Comment: No I just mean Same codes result different output. In my case c cloumn not 0.1, 0.2 ...but 1.0, 1.0,1.0, 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Elior's answer and responding to Erkan, the reason the output is 1.0 for each column is that the partitionBy(F.col("value")) partitions the data as a single row per partition such that when the window calculates `cume_dist` it does it for a single value and results with 1.0.

Removing the partitionBy(F.col("value")) from the window operation results in the expected quantiles.

---

**Start of Elior's Answer**

---

If you don't wanna use spark-sql (as I do) you can use the `cume_dist` function.
See example below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val df = (1 to 10).toSeq.toDF
val win = Window.
    partitionBy(F.col("value")).    //Remove this line
    orderBy(F.col("value")).
    rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
df.withColumn("c", F.cume_dist().over(win)).show
```

Results:

```
+-----+---+
|value|  c|
+-----+---+
|    1|0.1|
|    2|0.2|
|    3|0.3|
|    4|0.4|
|    5|0.5|
|    6|0.6|
|    7|0.7|
|    8|0.8|
|    9|0.9|
|   10|1.0|
+-----+---+
```

The median is the value for which `df("c")` equals 0.5. I hope it helps, Elior.

---

**End of Elior's Answer**

---

Window defined without partitionBy:

```
val win = Window.
    orderBy(F.col("value")).
    rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
df.withColumn("c", F.cume_dist().over(win)).show
```