# outlier detection in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark data frame as shown below.

```
+---+-------+--------+
|age|balance|duration|
+---+-------+--------+
|  2|   2143|     261|
| 44|     29|     151|
| 33|      2|      76|
| 50|   1506|      92|
| 33|      1|     198|
| 35|    231|     139|
| 28|    447|     217|
|  2|      2|     380|
| 58|    121|      50|
| 43|    693|      55|
| 41|    270|     222|
| 50|    390|     137|
| 53|      6|     517|
| 58|     71|      71|
| 57|    162|     174|
| 40|    229|     353|
| 45|     13|      98|
| 57|     52|      38|
|  3|      0|     219|
|  4|      0|      54|
+---+-------+--------+
```

and my expected output should be look like,

```
+---+-------+--------+-------+-----------+------------+
|age|balance|duration|age_out|balance_out|duration_out|
+---+-------+--------+-------+-----------+------------+
|  2|   2143|     261|      1|          1|           0|
| 44|     29|     151|      0|          0|           0|
| 33|      2|      76|      0|          0|           0|
| 50|   1506|      92|      0|          1|           0|
| 33|      1|     198|      0|          0|           0|
| 35|    231|     139|      0|          0|           0|
| 28|    447|     217|      0|          0|           0|
|  2|      2|     380|      1|          0|           0|
| 58|    121|      50|      0|          0|           0|
| 43|    693|      55|      0|          0|           0|
| 41|    270|     222|      0|          0|           0|
| 50|    390|     137|      0|          0|           0|
| 53|      6|     517|      0|          0|           1|
| 58|     71|      71|      0|          0|           0|
| 57|    162|     174|      0|          0|           0|
| 40|    229|     353|      0|          0|           0|
| 45|     13|      98|      0|          0|           0|
| 57|     52|      38|      0|          0|           0|
|  3|      0|     219|      1|          0|           0|
|  4|      0|      54|      0|          0|           0|
+---+-------+--------+-------+-----------+------------+
```

Here my objective is to identify the outlier records in the data set by using inter quartile method as I described in the below python code. If we find any outlier records, then we need to flag them as 1 otherwise 0.

I can do the same thing using python by using below code.

```
import numpy as np
def outliers_iqr(ys):
    quartile_1, quartile_3 = np.percentile(ys, [25, 75])
    iqr = quartile_3 - quartile_1
    lower_bound = quartile_1 - (iqr * 1.5)
    upper_bound = quartile_3 + (iqr * 1.5)
    ser = np.zeros(len(ys))
    pos =np.where((ys > upper_bound) | (ys < lower_bound))[0]
    ser[pos]=1
    return(ser)
```

But I wanted to do the same thing in pyspark. Can someone help me on the same?

my pyspark code:

```
def outliers_iqr(ys):
    quartile_1, quartile_3 = np.percentile(ys, [25, 75])
    iqr = quartile_3 - quartile_1
    lower_bound = quartile_1 - (iqr * 1.5)
    upper_bound = quartile_3 + (iqr * 1.5)
    ser = np.zeros(len(ys))
    pos =np.where((ys > upper_bound) | (ys < lower_bound))[0]
    ser[pos]=1
    return(float(ser))

outliers_iqr_udf = udf(outliers_iqr, FloatType())
DF.withColumn('age_out', outliers_iqr_udf(DF.select('age').collect())).show()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[You can use `pyspark.sql.DataFrame.approxQuantile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432843/how-to-find-median-and-quantiles-using-spark) inside of a loop to get the desired 25th and 75th percentile values for each of your columns.

```python
bounds = {
    c: dict(
        zip(["q1", "q3"], df.approxQuantile(c, [0.25, 0.75], 0))
    )
    for c in df.columns
}
```

The last argument passed is the relative error, which you can read about on the linked post as well as on the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.approxQuantile). The short version is that the lower the number, the more accurate your result will be but there is a trade-off between accuracy and computational expense. (Here I used 0 to get the exact value, but you may want to choose a different value based on the size of your data.)

Once you have the first and third quartile values, you can compute the `iqr` and upper/lower bounds quite easily:

```python
for c in bounds:
    iqr = bounds[c]['q3'] - bounds[c]['q1']
    bounds[c]['lower'] = bounds[c]['q1'] - (iqr * 1.5)
    bounds[c]['upper'] = bounds[c]['q3'] + (iqr * 1.5)
print(bounds)
#{'age': {'lower': 3.0, 'q1': 33.0, 'q3': 53.0, 'upper': 83.0},
# 'balance': {'lower': -570.0, 'q1': 6.0, 'q3': 390.0, 'upper': 966.0},
# 'duration': {'lower': -143.0, 'q1': 76.0, 'q3': 222.0, 'upper': 441.0}}
```

Now use `pyspark.sql.functions.when` in a list comprehension to build the outlier columns based on `bounds`:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.select(
    "*",
    *[
        f.when(
            f.col(c).between(bounds[c]['lower'], bounds[c]['upper']),
            0
        ).otherwise(1).alias(c+"_out") 
        for c in df.columns
    ]
).show()
#+---+-------+--------+-------+-----------+------------+
#|age|balance|duration|age_out|balance_out|duration_out|
#+---+-------+--------+-------+-----------+------------+
#|  2|   2143|     261|      1|          1|           0|
#| 44|     29|     151|      0|          0|           0|
#| 33|      2|      76|      0|          0|           0|
#| 50|   1506|      92|      0|          1|           0|
#| 33|      1|     198|      0|          0|           0|
#| 35|    231|     139|      0|          0|           0|
#| 28|    447|     217|      0|          0|           0|
#|  2|      2|     380|      1|          0|           0|
#| 58|    121|      50|      0|          0|           0|
#| 43|    693|      55|      0|          0|           0|
#| 41|    270|     222|      0|          0|           0|
#| 50|    390|     137|      0|          0|           0|
#| 53|      6|     517|      0|          0|           1|
#| 58|     71|      71|      0|          0|           0|
#| 57|    162|     174|      0|          0|           0|
#| 40|    229|     353|      0|          0|           0|
#| 45|     13|      98|      0|          0|           0|
#| 57|     52|      38|      0|          0|           0|
#|  3|      0|     219|      0|          0|           0|
#|  4|      0|      54|      0|          0|           0|
#+---+-------+--------+-------+-----------+------------+
```

Here I used `between` to check if a value is not an outlier, and this function is inclusive (ie `x between a and b` is logically equivalent to `x >= a and x <= b`).

Comment: Is it possible to solve this problem with my function? If so, please guide me what changes are required to make it work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RSK I don't see any easy way to modify your original code to accomplish this in spark.

Comment: What does this f stand for. In my case it says that there is no variable called f??

Comment: @Saradamani edited answer to include `import pyspark.sql.functions as f`

Comment: So these are the observations across all the columns that are within the iqr. Correct me if I am wrong..Please

Comment: @Saradamani each `_out` column is an indicator that specifies if the value in that row for the corresponding column is an outlier.

Comment: I have faced a terrible problem. What I am trying to do is to remove all the outliers from the whole data set . Like say I have row numbers 1,2 4,7 as outliers but row numbers 3,5,6,8,9,10 as not outliers. But here what I get is whether the value of an observation for an attribute is an outlier or not. But I want to detect and remove or isolate all the outliers detected by something like Maholanobis distance from the dataset. But this code does not help me on it. Why I want to do this? My accuracy is low if I do not delete the outliers from the dataset. Can you do the same for me?

Comment: What I want to do is this:  1.calculating the column mean  2.calculating variance covariance matrix       3. adding the mean vector to the existing dataset  4.calculating the moholanobish distance 5.Find out the iqr     6.create a column called distance in the dataset      7. df_without_outlier = df(distance <3rd quartile +1.5*iqr))

Comment: @pault How do I edit your code to just get the outliers for a specific column, let's  say take it as an input and just perform this operation on that column only?

Comment: @codingenthusiast the dict and list comprehensions are over the columns you want to perform the operation on. In this example, we used `df.columns`, but you can also specify your own subset of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Please find below my solution:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f


class Outlier():

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df


    def _calculate_bounds(self):
        bounds = {
            c: dict(
                zip(["q1", "q3"], self.df.approxQuantile(c, [0.25, 0.75], 0))
            )
            for c, d in zip(self.df.columns, self.df.dtypes) if d[1] in ["bigint", "double"]
        }

        for c in bounds:
            iqr = bounds[c]['q3'] - bounds[c]['q1']
            bounds[c]['min'] = bounds[c]['q1'] - (iqr * 1.5)
            bounds[c]['max'] = bounds[c]['q3'] + (iqr * 1.5)

        return bounds


    def _flag_outliers_df(self):
        bounds = self._calculate_bounds()

        outliers_col = [
            f.when(
                ~f.col(c).between(bounds[c]['min'], bounds[c]['max']),
                f.col(c)
            ).alias(c + '_outlier')
            for c in bounds]

        return self.df.select(*outliers_col)


    def show_outliers(self):

        outlier_df = self._flag_outliers_df()

        for outlier in outlier_df.columns:
            outlier_df.select(outlier).filter(f.col(outlier).isNotNull()).show()
```

And then pass your dataframe as below:

```py
Outlier(df).show_outliers()
```