# What are alternative methods for pandas quantile and cut in pyspark 1.6

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm newbie to pyspark. I have pandas code like below.

```
bindt = df[df[var].notnull()][var].quantile([0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1]).unique()

df['{0}_quartile'.format(var)] = pd.cut(df[var], bindt, labels=False, include_lowest=True )
```

I have found 'approxQuantile' in pyspark 2.x but I didn't find any such in pyspark 1.6.0

**My sample input**:

df.show()

```
+-----------+----------+---------------+--------------+------------------------+
|  id       | col_1    |col_2          |col_3         |col_4                   |
+-----------+----------+---------------+--------------+------------------------+
|1.10919E+16|3988487.35|     -236751.43|    -362208.07|                0.660000|
|1.10919E+16|3988487.35|     -236751.43|    -362208.07|                0.900000|
|1.10919E+16|3988487.35|     -236751.43|    -362208.07|                0.660000|
|1.10919E+16|  36718.55|           null|          null|                0.860000|
|1.10919E+16|  36718.55|           null|          null|                0.780000|
|1.10919E+16|  36718.55|           null|          null|                0.660000|
|1.10919E+16|  36718.55|           null|          null|                0.900000|
|1.10919E+16|  36718.55|           null|          null|                0.660000|
```

df.collect()

```
[Row(id=u'1.11312E+16', col_1=Decimal('367364.44'), col_2=Decimal('-401715.23'), col_3=Decimal('-1649917.53'), col_4=Decimal('0.080000')), 
Row(id=u'1.11312E+16', col_1=Decimal('367364.44'), col_2=Decimal('-401715.23'), col_3=Decimal('-1649917.53'), col_4=Decimal('0.780000')), 
Row(id=u'1.11312E+16', col_1=Decimal('367364.44'), col_2=Decimal('-401715.23'), col_3=Decimal('-1649917.53'), col_4=Decimal('0.780000')), 
Row(id=u'1.11312E+16', col_1=Decimal('367364.44'), col_2=Decimal('-401715.23'), col_3=Decimal('-1649917.53'), col_4=Decimal('0.860000')), 
Row(id=u'1.11312E+16', col_1=Decimal('367364.44'), col_2=Decimal('-401715.23'), col_3=Decimal('-1649917.53'), col_4=Decimal('0.330000'))]
```

I have to loop the above logic for all input columns.

```
for var in df.columns:
    bindt = df[df[var].notnull()][var].quantile([0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1]).unique()    
    df['{0}_quartile'.format(var)] = pd.cut(df[var], bindt, labels=False, include_lowest=True )
```

Could anyone please suggest how to rewrite above code in pyspark 1.6 dataframe.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please make the sample input executable. Nonsense symbols like `+`, `-` and `|` make copy&pasting the data sample really nasty. Furthermore `var` in your code sample is not in the dataframe/ not a defined variable.

Comment: @Scotty1- I have edited my question. Please check once and let me know if you find any solution. Thanks

Comment: By rewrite, do you mean, convert the code from pandas to pyspark, or loop through the pandas dataframe, and insert it into a pyspark dataframe?

Comment: @Xilpex - Yes, I want to convert the code from pandas to pyspark.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using pyspark 2.x, you can use [QuantileDiscretizer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#quantilediscretizer) from ml lib which uses [approxQuantile()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions.approxQuantile) and [Bucketizer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#bucketizer) under the hood.

However, since you're using pyspark 1.6.x you need to:

#### 1. Find the quantile values of a column

You can find the quantile values in two ways:

1. Compute the percentile of a column by computing the [percent_rank()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.percent_rank) and extract the column values which has percentile value close to the quantile that you want
2. Follow [the methods in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432843/how-to-find-median-and-quantiles-using-spark) which explains how to perform quantile approximations with pyspark < 2.0.0

Here's my example implementation of approximating quantile values:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

def compute_quantiles(df, col, quantiles):
  quantiles = sorted(quantiles)

  # 1. compute percentile
  df = df.withColumn("percentile", F.percent_rank().over(Window.orderBy(col)))

  # 2. categorize quantile based on the desired quantile and compute errors
  df = df.withColumn("percentile_cat1", F.lit(-1.0))
  df = df.withColumn("percentile_err1", F.lit(-1.0))
  df = df.withColumn("percentile_cat2", F.lit(-1.0))
  df = df.withColumn("percentile_err2", F.lit(-1.0))

  # check percentile with the lower boundaries
  for idx in range(0, len(quantiles)-1):
    q = quantiles[idx]
    df = df.withColumn("percentile_cat1", F\
                       .when( (F.col("percentile_cat1") == -1.0) & 
                             (F.col("percentile") <= q), q)\
                       .otherwise(F.col("percentile_cat1")))
    df = df.withColumn("percentile_err1", F\
                       .when( (F.col("percentile_err1") == -1.0) & 
                             (F.col("percentile") <= q), 
                             F.pow(F.col("percentile") - q, 2))\
                       .otherwise(F.col("percentile_err1")))

  # assign the remaining -1 values in the error to the largest squared error of 1
  df = df.withColumn("percentile_err1", F\
                     .when(F.col("percentile_err1") == -1.0, 1)\
                     .otherwise(F.col("percentile_err1")))

  # check percentile with the upper boundaries
  for idx in range(1, len(quantiles)):
    q = quantiles[idx]
    df = df.withColumn("percentile_cat2", F\
                       .when((F.col("percentile_cat2") == -1.0) & 
                             (F.col("percentile") <= q), q)\
                       .otherwise(F.col("percentile_cat2")))
    df = df.withColumn("percentile_err2",F\
                       .when((F.col("percentile_err2") == -1.0) & 
                             (F.col("percentile") <= q), 
                             F.pow(F.col("percentile") - q, 2))\
                       .otherwise(F.col("percentile_err2")))

  # assign the remaining -1 values in the error to the largest squared error of 1
  df = df.withColumn("percentile_err2", F\
                     .when(F.col("percentile_err2") == -1.0, 1)\
                     .otherwise(F.col("percentile_err2")))

  # select the nearest quantile to the percentile
  df = df.withColumn("percentile_cat", F\
                     .when(F.col("percentile_err1") < F.col("percentile_err2"), 
                           F.col("percentile_cat1"))\
                     .otherwise(F.col("percentile_cat2")))
  df = df.withColumn("percentile_err", F\
                     .when(F.col("percentile_err1") < F.col("percentile_err2"), 
                           F.col("percentile_err1"))\
                     .otherwise(F.col("percentile_err2")))

  # 3. approximate quantile values by choosing the value with the lowest error at each percentile category
  df = df.withColumn("approx_quantile", F\
                     .first(col).over(Window\
                                      .partitionBy("percentile_cat")\
                                      .orderBy(F.asc("percentile_err"))))

  return df

def extract_quantiles(df):
  df_quantiles = df.select("percentile_cat", "approx_quantile").distinct()
  rows = df_quantiles.collect()
  quantile_values = [ row.approx_quantile for row in rows ]

  return quantile_values
```

What I wanted to achieve from above is computing the percentile of each row in the column, and categorizing it to the nearest quantile. Categorizing a percentile to nearest quantile can be done by choosing the lowest quantile category which has the lowest difference (squared error) to the percentile.

**1. Computing Percentile**

First, I compute the percentile of a column using the [percent_rank()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.percent_rank), a [Window function](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) in pyspark. You can think of Window as a partition specification for your data. Since `percent_rank()` is a Window function, so you need to pass in the Window.

**2. Categorize percentile to quantile boundaries and compute errors**

The nearest quantile category to a percentile can be *below, equal to* or *above it*. Hence, I need to compute the errors twice: first to compare the percentile with the lower quantile bounds, and the second to compare it with the upper quantile bounds. Note the ≤ operator is used to check whether the percentile is less than or **equal to** the boundaries. After knowing the direct upper and lower quantile boundaries of a percentile, we can assign a percentile to the nearest quantile category by choosing either the quantile below-or-equal or above-or-equal category which has the lowest error.

**3. Approximate quantile values**

Once we know all the closest quantile categories per each percentile, we can then approx the quantile values: it's the value which has the lowest errors at each quantile category. This approx quantile values can be computed using [`first()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.first) function at each category partition using [Window](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html). Next, to extract the quantile values, we can just select the unique percentileCategory-approxQuantileValue pairs from the dataframe.

---

After testing for my data (~10000 rows) with `desired_quantiles = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]`, I found that my example implementation is quite close to `approxQuantile` results. Both result values get even closer as I decrease the error supplied to `approxQuantile`.

Using `extract_quantiles(compute_quantile(df, col, quantiles))`:

[image]

Using `approxQuantile`:

[image]

#### 2. Use Bucketizer

After finding the quantile values, you can use pyspark's Bucketizer to bucketize values based on the quantile. Bucketizer is available in both pyspark 1.6.x [[1]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/ml-features.html#bucketizer)[[2]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.Bucketizer) and 2.x [[3]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/ml-features.html#bucketizer)[[4]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.Bucketizer)

Here is an example of how you can perform bucketization:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import Bucketizer

bucketedData = df
desired_quantiles = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0] # must be sorted

for col in df.columns:
  quantile_values = extract_quantiles(compute_quantiles(df, col, desired_quantiles))
  splits = [ boundary_values ] # replace this with quantile_values

  bucketizer = Bucketizer()\
    .setInputCol(col)\
    .setOutputCol("{}_quantile".format(col))\
    .setSplits(splits)
  bucketedData = bucketizer.transform(bucketedData)
```

You can replace `value_boundaries` with the quantile values you found in step 1 or any bucket split range that you desire. When you're using bucketizer, **the whole column value range must be covered within the splits**. Otherwise, values outside the splits specified will be treated as errors. Infinite values such as `-float("inf")`, `float("inf")` must be explicitly provided to cover all the floating values if you're unsure about the value boundaries of your data.

Comment: Hi @dekauliya - Thanks for your reply. I have few questions. 1) Is desired_quantiles means [0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1] ? 2) I didn't get second step, I mean calculation of percentile_cat1, percentile_cat2 and percentile_err1. Can you please explain me in detail as I'm beginner level. 3) Can we use this 'compute_quantiles' method as a replacement of 'approxQuantile' in pyspark 1.6?

Comment: 3) okay, after trying out the code and comparing it to results obtained from `approxQuantile`, it seems that my experimental algo is comparable and can be used as replacement for `approxQuantile`. If you have pyspark 2.x available it's better to use `approxQuantile` instead though

Comment: 1) yes, 2) what I wanted to achieve is computing the percentile of each row in the column, and categorizing it to the nearest quantile, it's a bit long I'll update my answer then