# databricks.koalas has no attribute 'qcut' for decile

Tags: databricks, spark-koalas

I am using koalas in databricks and trying to decile the data.

Therefore I used

`df['Decile']= ks.qcut(df['Id'],  q = 10, labels = False)`

I am getting AttributeError: module 'databricks.koalas' has no attribute 'qcut'

Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

**koalas** does not support qcut. Though you can do it natively in PySpark, see [What are alternative methods for pandas quantile and cut in pyspark 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54803107).