# Best way to handle medium for large dataset

Tags: apache-spark, quantile

I'm using spark to find medium for large dataset, around(300PB). What's the best way to optimize? (BTW, the result doesn't have to be strictly accurate)

Comment: you mean, median?

Comment: hope this helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432843/how-to-find-median-and-quantiles-using-spark

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this problem in two way:
1-using **meanApprox**(long **timeout**, double **confidence**) function which returns the approximate mean within a timeout and confidence.

2-You can use **Sample**(double **fraction**, boolean **withReplacement**, long **seed**, SparkPlan **child**)  method for doing your purpose for example:

```
sampledRDD = rdd.sample(False, sample, seed)
approxMean = sampledRDD.mean()
```

I wish this will you to solve your problem.
for more detail you could visit https://spark.apache.org/docs for more information.

Comment: Does find median for sample gives you a similar number to the whole dataset. How to ensure they are similar?

Comment: For "mean", "count" and "sum" we could provide confidence in relate to size of sample but for median,  It depends if your data is sorted or not.

Comment: Why does sorted or not matter? what are the differences?