# How would I filter a dataframe by a column's percentile value in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Say I have this dataframe:

```
  val df = Seq(("Mike",1),("Kevin",2),("Bob",3),("Steve",4)).toDF("name","score")
```

[image]

and I want to filter this dataframe so that it only returns rows where the "score" column is greater than on equal to the 75th percentile. How would I do this?

Thanks so much and have a great day!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find median and quantiles using Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432843/how-to-find-median-and-quantiles-using-spark)

Comment: Thanks, but how would I add this as a new column to the dataframe with the corresponding percentiles?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to base your filter on is the [upper quartile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile).

> It is also known as the upper quartile or the 75th empirical quartile and 75% of the data lies below this point.

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432843/how-to-find-median-and-quantiles-using-spark), you can use spark's `approximateQuantile` to get what you want:

```
val q = df.stat.approxQuantile("score", Array(.75), 0)
q: Array[Double] = Array(3.0)
```

This array(`q`) gives you the boundary between 3rd and 4th quartiles.

Using a simple spark filter should get you what you want:

```
df.filter($"score" >= q.head).show
+-----+-----+
| name|score|
+-----+-----+
|  Bob|    3|
|Steve|    4|
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: @koh-ding : if this answer solves your problem, please accept it. If you need something more, please let me know so I can improve the answer.