# How to perform basic statistics on a Json file to explore my numeric and non-numeric variable?

Tags: json, apache-spark, statistics, frequency, mean

I've imported a Json file which has this schema :

```
sqlContext.read.json("filename").printSchema 
   root 
 |-- COL: long (nullable = true) 
 |-- DATA: array (nullable = true) 
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true) 
 |    |    |-- Crate: string (nullable = true) 
 |    |    |-- MLrate: string (nullable = true) 
 |    |    |-- Nrout: string (nullable = true) 
 |    |    |-- up: string (nullable = true) 
 |-- IFAM: string (nullable = true) 
 |-- KTM: long (nullable = true)
```

I'm new on Spark and I want to perform basic statistics like

- getting the min, max, mean, median and std of numeric variables
- getting the values frequencies for non-numeric variables.

My questions are :

- How to change the type of my variables in my schema, from 'string' to 'numeric' ? (Crate, MLrate and Nrout should be numeric variables) ?
- How to do those basic statistics easily ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to change the type of my variables in my schema, from 'string' to 'numeric' ? (Crate, MLrate and Nrout should be numeric variables) ?

You can create schema manually and apply it to the existing RDD. I assume your data is stored in a `df` variable and has the same structure as an example from your previous question:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val schema = StructType(
    StructField("COL", LongType, true) ::
    StructField("DATA", ArrayType(StructType(
        StructField("Crate", IntegerType, true) ::
        StructField("MLrate", IntegerType, true) ::
        StructField("Nrout", IntegerType, true) ::
        StructField("up", IntegerType, true) ::
        Nil
    ), true), true) :: 
    StructField("IFAM", StringType, true) :: 
    StructField("KTM", LongType, true) :: 
    Nil
)

def convert(row: Row) = {
    val col = row.get(0)
    val data: Seq[Row] = row.getSeq(1)
    val rowData = data.map(r => Row.fromSeq(r.toSeq.map{
        case v: String => v.toInt
        case _ => null
    })).toList
    val ifam = row.get(2)
    val ktm = row.get(3)
    Row(col, rowData, ifam, ktm)
}

val updatedDf = sqlContext.applySchema(df.rdd.map(convert), schema)
updatedDf.printSchema
```

and we get expected output:

```
root
 |-- COL: long (nullable = true)
 |-- DATA: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Crate: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- MLrate: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Nrout: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- up: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- IFAM: string (nullable = true)
 |-- KTM: long (nullable = true)
```

You can adjust numeric type (`DecimalType`, `DoubleType` according to your requirements).

> getting the min, max, mean, <s>median</s> and std of numeric variables
>   How to do those basic statistics easily ?

The simplest way to obtain statistics for numeric variables is to use `describe` method:

```
updatedDf.describe().show
```

and you get nicely formatted output:

```
+-------+----+-------------+
|summary| COL|          KTM|
+-------+----+-------------+
|  count|   2|            2|
|   mean|21.5| 1.4300064E12|
| stddev| 0.5|         null|
|    min|  21|1430006400000|
|    max|  22|1430006400000|
+-------+----+-------------+
```

If you need an output you can access programmatically you can `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.agg(
    min("KTM").alias("KTM_min"),
    max("KTM").alias("KTM_max"),
    mean("KTM").alias("KTM_mean")).show
```

None of the above will work with array field though. To work with these you'll probably need an `udf` or flatten your structure first.

```
val flattenedSchema = StructType(
    StructField("COL", LongType, true) ::
    StructField("Crate", IntegerType, true) ::
    StructField("MLrate", IntegerType, true) ::
    StructField("Nrout", IntegerType, true) ::
    StructField("up", IntegerType, true) ::
    StructField("IFAM", StringType, true) :: 
    StructField("KTM", LongType, true) :: 
    Nil
)

def flatten(row: Row) = {
    val col = row.get(0)
    val data: Seq[Row] = row.getSeq(1)
    val ifam = row.get(2)
    val ktm = row.get(3)

    data.map(dat => {
        val crate = dat.get(0)
        val mlrate = dat.get(1)
        val nrout = dat.get(2)
        val up = dat.get(3)
        Row(col, crate, mlrate, nrout, up, ifam, ktm)
    })
}

val updatedFlatDf = sqlContext.
    applySchema(updatedDf.rdd.flatMap(flatten), flattenedSchema)

updatedFlatDf.describe().show
```

Now you can stats for each field:

```
+-------+----+------------------+------------------+------------------+----+-------------+
|summary| COL|             Crate|            MLrate|             Nrout|  up|          KTM|
+-------+----+------------------+------------------+------------------+----+-------------+
|  count|  12|                12|                12|                12|   0|           12|
|   mean|21.5|2.1666666666666665|             31.75|2.3333333333333335|null| 1.4300064E12|
| stddev| 0.5|1.2133516482134201|2.5535922410074345| 3.223179934302286|null|         null|
|    min|  21|                 0|                30|                 0|null|1430006400000|
|    max|  22|                 5|                38|                 8|null|1430006400000|
+-------+----+------------------+------------------+------------------+----+-------------+
```

> getting the <s>min, max, mean</s>, median <s>and std</s> of numeric variables

Getting quantiles, including median, is usually far to expensive for large datasets. If you really have to compute median you may [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31437177/1560062) for [How to find median using Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31432843/1560062) useful. It is written in Python but pretty easy to implement in Scala as well. A little bit less comprehensive answer in Scala has been provided by [Eugene Zhulenev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1177991/eugene-zhulenev) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28160731/1560062).

**EDIT**:

If you want to convert `nrout` to date you can replace `rowData` inside `convert` with something like this:

```
val rowData = data.map(dat => {
    val crate = dat.get(0).toInt
    val mlrate = dat.get(1).toInt
    val nrout = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(dat.get(2))
    val up = dat.get(3).toInt
    Row(crate, mlrate, nrout, up)
})
```

and adjust schema:

```
StructField("Nrout", TimestampType, true)
```

Comment: My variable "Nrout" has values like "2012-11-01 20:13:00.0" so I try to put it in StringType in my Schema but I got an error.... Is there a DateTime format?

Comment: Yes, there is `DateType`, but you'll have to convert your field to `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: You mean I have to "import java.sql.Date" before ?

Comment: I do not exactly understand what you mean with java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(_), can you give an example or correct directly in your code?